# how can pass function as argument php class

Tags: php

I want to write a class to submit using the function method and get access to example_method at the class

```
$users = User::where('posts', function($q){
    $q->example_method ('created_at', '>=', '2015-01-01 00:00:00');
})->get() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand - you want to have access to `$q` variable in anonymous function, you can access it this way:

```
$users = User::where('posts', function() use ($q) {
    $q->example_method ('created_at', '>=', '2015-01-01 00:00:00');
})->get() ;
```

In case you want access variable defined outside function you have to inherit it using `use`.

More info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php